# Why does a Timestamp and int not work as an input for plotly scatterplots?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite, plotly

I am using [this](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/ridgeline-graph-plotly) guide as a template to display cpu persentages over time.  I have a sqlite3 database with value collected by another script. When i try to plot with the timestamp as the X axis i get a blank plot.
"
x=df.loc[df['Hostname'] == client]['Timestamp'],
y=df.loc[df['Hostname'] == client]['Cpu_percent'],
" is the part which is not working as far as i can see.

New to plotting. Learning as i go :)

```
# getting necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import sqlite3 as sql

# getting the data
# Read sqlite query results into a pandas DataFrame
DB = sql.connect("history.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM HOSTDATA WHERE Timestamp > datetime('now', '-50 minutes')", DB)
DB.close()
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print("test dataframe")
print(df)
DB.close()

#print(df.loc[df['Hostname'] == 'USNL01']['Cpu_percent'])

def Plotcpu():
    # for loop die door unieke Hostname waardes gaat
    print("test forloop unieke clients")
    fig = go.Figure()
    i=0
    for client in df['Hostname'].unique():
        print(client)
        spacing = int(i / len(df['Hostname'].unique()) * 100)
        print(spacing)

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=[-55, 0], y=np.full(2, spacing),
            mode='lines',
            line_color='white'))

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=df.loc[df['Hostname'] == client]['Timestamp'],
            y=df.loc[df['Hostname'] == client]['Cpu_percent'],
            fill='tonexty',
            name=client))

        fig.add_annotation(
            x=-52,
            y=spacing,
            text=client,
            showarrow=False,
            yshift=10)
        i = i + 1


    fig.update_layout(
        title='Cpu gebruik',
        showlegend=False,
        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False)  # that way you hide the y axis ticks labels
    )

    fig.write_html("plot.html")

Plotcpu()
```

Comment: Can you please privide some sampledata so we can try ourselves? Just from looking at your code it's hard to tell, maybe the plot display is "zoomed" in too much since timestamps as ints are quite big numbers.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x-axis of the referenced case study is numerical, so it should be replaced with a time series for your data. The way this graph works is simply that the starting position of the y-axis, which is the basis of each line graph, is shifted by a certain constant. So I am assuming that the expected value is a percentage, so I use 100 plus 10 in the margin as the interval value, assuming that the value does not exceed 100. The client name is set for the x-axis position based on the graph size standard (`paper`). Finally, I set the template to no template to make it look like a ridgeline graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=50) 
end = datetime.datetime.now()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname': sum([['host'+str(x) for x in range(10)]]*100, []),
                   'Timestamp': sum([[time]*10 for time in pd.date_range(start, end, freq='30s')[:-1]],[]),
                   'Cpu_percent': sum([np.random.randint(0,101,10).tolist() for x in range(100)], [])})

df.head()
    Hostname    Timestamp   Cpu_percent
0   host0   2022-08-03 11:48:13.620316  5
1   host1   2022-08-03 11:48:13.620316  19
2   host2   2022-08-03 11:48:13.620316  26
3   host3   2022-08-03 11:48:13.620316  68
4   host4   2022-08-03 11:48:13.620316  42

import plotly.graph_objects as go

# host_max = df.groupby('Hostname')['Cpu_percent'].max()
fig = go.Figure()

for i,client in enumerate(df['Hostname'].unique()):
    spacing = int(i * 110)
    dff = df[df['Hostname'] == client]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=dff['Timestamp'],
        y=np.full(len(dff['Timestamp']),spacing),
        mode='lines',
        line_color='white'
    ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=dff['Timestamp'],
        y=dff['Cpu_percent']+110*i,
        fill='tonexty',
        name=client
    ))
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=-0.05,
        xref='paper',
        y=spacing,
        yref='y',
        text=client,
        showarrow=False,
        yshift=10
    )

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    height=800,
    title='Cpu gebruik',
    showlegend=False,
    yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    template='none'
)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,1100])

fig.show()
```

[image]